Confusion on proof of a polynomial of degree n is $\Omega (x^n)$

This is a solution from Rosen's Discrete Math textbook for the problem of proving a polynomial of degree n is of order $x^n$, that is $\Theta(x^n)$.
I understand the proof for the polynomial of degree n being $O(n)$, but the proof of the polynomial being $\Omega (n)$ is confusing me here.
In particular, I'm not understanding 3 things:

Why is "k be chosen larger than 1 and $2nm/|a_{n}|$, where $m$ is the largest of the absolute values of the $a_{i}$'s for $i < n$"?
How do we prove "each $a_{n-i}/x^i$ is smaller than $|a_{n}|/2n$ in absolute value for all $x > k$" (what does "in absolute value" mean here?) ?
How did we go from the line 2 to line 3 in the proof (the one's marked with red arrows)?

Kindly please do help explain.

question 3: $|a_n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}| \ge |a_n| - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}| \ge |a_n| - n \frac{|a_{n}|}{2 n} = \frac{|a_{n}|}{2} $ where $|\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}| \le \frac{|a_{n}|}{2 n} $ was stated in the textbook.

@Andreas sorry how'd you get $|a_{n} + \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}| \geq |a_{n}| - \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} |\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}|$ ?

@Andreas and how'd you prove $|\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}| \leq \frac{|a_{n}|}{2n}$ ?

Also technically shouldn't the sum go from 1 -> n instead of 0 -> (n-1)?

We look at the settings and the estimations in some more detail. This should clarify all three questions. We consider a polynomial function
\begin{align*}
f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0
\end{align*}
and use according to the book the following settings
\begin{align*}
m&:=\max\{|a_0|,|a_1|,\ldots,|a_{n-1}|\}\tag{1}\\
k&>\max\left\{1,\frac{2mn}{|a_n|}\right\}\tag{2}\\
x&>k\tag{3}
\end{align*}
We derive a series of inequalities from (1) - (3), from which we derive the inequality pointed to by the red arrows. From (1) to (3) we get
\begin{align*}
\max\left\{1,\frac{2mn}{|a_n|}\right\}<k<x\leq x^i\qquad\qquad 1\leq i\leq n
\end{align*}
It follows foreach coefficient $a_{n-i}$
\begin{align*}
\frac{2na_{n-i}}{|a_n|}&\leq \frac{2mn}{|a_n|}<x^i\qquad\qquad\  1\leq i\leq n\\
\end{align*}
Rearranging left and right part gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}&<\frac{|a_n|}{2n}\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 1\leq i\leq n
\end{align*}
Summing up we get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}<\frac{|a_n|}{2}}\tag{4}\\
\end{align*}
From the clever settings (1) - (3) we derive inequality (4) which is the key to do the inequality estimation.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{|f(x)|}&=\left|a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\right|\\
&=x^n\left|a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{x^{n-1}}+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right|\\
&=x^n\left|a_n+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}\right|\\
&\geq x^n\left||a_n|-\left|\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_{n-i}}{x^i}\right|\right|\tag{$\to \Delta$-inequality}\\
&\geq x^n\left(|a_n|-\frac{|a_n|}{2}\right)\tag{$\to$ (4)}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=x^n\frac{|a_n|}{2}}
\end{align*}
according to the claim.


So we assume n >= 1?

Also, shouldn't it technically be: \begin{align*}
\frac{2n|a_{n-i}|}{|a_n|}&\leq \frac{2mn}{|a_n|}<x^i\qquad\qquad\  1\leq i\leq n\
\end{align*} (because of how $m$ is defined)? I guess it would add the additional step of applying the regular triangle inequality (you already having applied the reverse triangle inequality)

Btw thank you so very much for the very detailed/rigorous answer! I truly appreciate it! I guess my only question remains is Q.1 of my post, which is how on earth did the author decide/think of using $2mn/|a_n|$?!

@BobMarley: You're welcome. :-) Yes, we consider $n\geq 1$. I think it is a matter of experience, where the triangle inequality is the main driver to derive the specific settings.
